# Trying push a string backwards into a vector

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class thing{
public:
    vector<unsigned short> vec;
    thing(string);
};

int main(){
    thing adam("12345");
    for(int i = adam.vec.size() - 1;i >= 0;i--){
        cout << adam.vec[i] << endl;
    }
}

thing::thing(string str){
    for(int i = str.size() - 1; i >= 0;i--){
        cout << str[i] << endl;
        vec.push_back(str[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a constructor that takes in a string and fills the vector with the string in reverse, but instead of filling the vector with the values `5,4,3,2,1`, it fills it with `53,52,51,59,49`. This happens when I call `push_back()` and I'm confused on why.

Comment: Hint: `std::string::rbegin` is a thing. As is constructing a string from a pair of (reverse) iterators. You are writing *way more* code than you need to in order to solve rhis.

Comment: This has nothing to do with strings or vectors. You'd get the same results by doing `unsigned short n = '5'; cout << n << "\n";`.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to make a constructor that takes in a string and fills the vector with the string in reverse

You probably don't really want to do that. As @JesperJuhl suggests - you can always just access the string in reverse. Why the needless copy?

> instead of filling the vector with the values 5,4,3,2,1, it fills it with 53,52,51,59,49

You're mistaking the characters `'5'`, `'4'`, `'3'` with their *integer values*. The values of string elements are numbers, but those numbers are indices into some character set. Without going into too much detail about - here's the relevant fragment of the character set in your case:

[image]

Indeed, the character `'5'` has index 53 (decimal) within the character set, `'4'` has 52 and so on.

Comment: We could do without another *image* of the ASCII table.

Comment: @n.m.: To be honest, this question is rather redundant. If you find a good dupe, I promise to remove my entire answer, not just the table...

Comment: I couldn't find a dupe though I know there are some.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for(int i = adam.vec.size() - 1;i >= 0;i--)
>     cout << adam.vec[i] << endl;
> ```

Your code to insert in reverse order is working just fine. But you are displaying the vector in reverse order also, so it goes back to previous order. To display in correct order, just use:

```
thing adam("12345");
for(size_t i = 0; i < adam.vec.size(); i++)
    cout << adam.vec[i] << ' ';
cout << endl;
//or 
for(const auto &element : adam.vec)
    cout << element << ' ';
cout << endl;
```

Your method `for(int i = str.size() - 1; i >= 0;i--){...}` for iterating backward works in most cases, but casting `size` in to `int` can be a problem. The standard library offers other methods. Example:

```
thing::thing(string str) 
{
    std::copy(str.crbegin(), str.crend(), std::back_inserter(vec));
}
```

Or use [iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) to traverse forward or backward.